# Resources for javascript alert

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an javascript alert :

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
       
        function checkDate(sender, args) {
            if (sender._selectedDate > new Date()) {
                alert("You can't select date later than today");
                
                sender._selectedDate = new Date();
                // set the date back to the current date
                sender._textbox.set_Value(null)
            }
        }
     
    </script>
```

I want that text "You can't select date later than today" to set in 2 languages, to localize it in 2 languages.When I chose my application in English that alert should be in English and so on. How is it possible?

P.S that javascript i am using inside the asp.net form

Comment: You need some tool/framework for localization, like jquery localization http://keith-wood.name/localisation.html

Comment: using ASP.NET Localization and _App_GlobalResources_, you can then get your text in other language when you switch languages. please take a look at this [site](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2006/Oct/31/Accessing-Localized-values-in-ASPNET-markup-and-JavaScript)